# Google AI Platform VM seems to not contain the official models repo

Tags: google-cloud-platform, tensorflow2.0, gcloud, gcp-ai-platform-training

I'm following the tutorial [Image Object Detection Custom Dataset — TensorFlow 2 Object Detection API](https://medium.com/swlh/image-object-detection-tensorflow-2-object-detection-api-af7244d4c34e) to launch a training task with Google gcloud. However the task terminates with the error

```
...File "/root/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/object_detection/models/ssd_efficientnet_bifpn_feature_extractor.py", line 33, in <module>
from official.vision.image_classification.efficientnet import efficientnet_model
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'official'
```

How come Google AI Platform VM does not contain the official models repo?

Comment: I found this SO thread which details some answers to your issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50121477. You may check if this applies to your use-case.

Comment: Thanks Rally. Yes I saw that thread before and actually I succeeded in training by telling gcloud to specifically install the module. I was only curious to know why the tensorflow VM does not include its official models module!

Comment: If you have followed the example provided which is done in Colab as stated in the documentation you provided, it is a possibility that the packages in Colab is not updated since TensorFlow is already pre-installed and optimized for the hardware being used.